# How do I print nested ArrayLists?

Tags: java

My fourth for loop, for (int y), keeps printing the first m elements over and over again, how can i fix it so that it prints m elements at a time but not the same ones?

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int n = input.nextInt();
int m = input.nextInt();

ArrayList<String> myname = new ArrayList<String>(n);
ArrayList<Integer> myscore = new ArrayList<Integer>(m);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { //swimmers
  myname.add(input.next());
  for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) { //judges
    myscore.add(input.nextInt());
  }
}
for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) { //name
  System.out.println(myname.get(x));

  for (int y = 0; y < m; y++) { //score
    System.out.println(myscore.get(y));
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and format your code properly, using your IDE's "format" option, so we can see which loops are nested and to which level. It's virtually unreadable right now.

Comment: You have no nested lists here

Comment: What do you mean with the same ones? It means without duplication? In that case it could be many cases for not printing m things

Comment: You are maintaining two separate list in above code.

Comment: Because you have a list `myscore` of `n*m` length not only `m` like you thought.

Comment: Not related to what is being asked but `input.nextInt()` returns an `int` i.e. the primitive type. You cannot add the input to your scores array as it is. You will need to box the input.

Comment: @B.Naeem, autoboxing exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code it seems that you have ‘n’ number of swimmers, each with ‘m’ number of scores. You are storing the names of the ‘n’ swimmers in an ArrayList, which is bad because you know the number will never change. A better approach to this would be to declare myname as a String[] of size n, and instead of calling myname.get(x) you would later call myname[x].
This however, is only symptomatically related to the problem at hand. You are storing all of your score results inside a single ArrayList. A better solution is to generate ‘n’ number of arrays (which is what I assume you would like to do based on the title of this question). This can be done by simply declaring 
allScores[][] = new int[n][m]

This would let you access the values for swimmer number ‘n’ with allScores[n]. If this isn’t what you actually wanted to do then you can simply offset the values in your last get statement by the number of scores you’ve already processed (x*n).

TLDR: Change the line in your last for loop to read:
System.out.println(myscore.get(y + x*n)

Comment: The TLDR worked, thank you!! I'll give it a shot and do it the way you suggested too.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have a list `myscore` of `n*m` length not only `m` like you thought. You are adding at the end of the list every score.

So you have `n` blocks of `m` elements in the list. You could still print the value with

```
for(int y = x * m, to = x*m + m; y < to; ++y){
    System.out.println(myscore.get(y));
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to get something like 

    Output of loop 1 : Output of loop 2, Output of loop 2 ...
    Output of loop 1 : Output of loop 2, Output of loop 2 ... 
and so on  for as many times as user wants. (if that makes sense)

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/dM7uh
see in the photo i put 2 numbers for each swimmer, and it shows the correct results for the first one, but for the second swimmer it shows the results of the first one again (3, 7), instead of his own (7, 6).

Comment: @Alberkko I get that, and since you have every score in the same list one after the other, the loop I have posted is targeting the correct block of score depending on the `x` multiply by `m` to start at the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ScoreHolder{

    String name = "";
    ArrayList<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>;


    public ScoreHolder(String name){
        this.name = name

}
}
```

And then

```
ScoreHolder[] scores = new ScoreHolder[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { //swimmers
  scores[i] = new ScoreHolder(input.next());
  for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) { //judges
    scores[i].scores.add(input.nextInt());
  }
}

for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) { //name
  System.out.println(scores[x].name);

  for (int y = 0; y < m; y++) { //score
    System.out.println(scores[x].scores.get(y));
  }
```

}

It won't be just easy to work with now but also a lot easier to make any changes or do anything else you want.

What I have done is simply created a holder class which will hold the swimmer's name and a list of all his scores.

This abstraction will now help you in getting the scores of the swimmers or doing anything else you now want with it.

Comment: Yeah, that looks like a much better way to do it. Thank you!

Comment: Definitly the "correct" solution, wasn't sure if OP knew how to manage POJO like this (well with getter/setter is better ;) ). PS : You should use `toString` to do the loop on the score list.